# How to mock ImagePicker

Tags: testing, flutter, camera, mocking, imagepicker

I use this package: [image picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker#-readme-tab-)
Now, I have this line of code:

```
File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
```

that I would like to mock in my test, but I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: check how flutter team [tests this package](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/image_picker/test/image_picker_test.dart). Maybe it will help

Comment: Posting the [new link for image picker test](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/main/packages/image_picker/image_picker/test/image_picker_test.dart) file, just in case

Comment: @Little Monkey did you have the chance to mock it? would you share how to?